# getting pbxes, sip2sip, ipkall all working

Tags: voip, sip

I was able to make a call from my landline to my ipkall number and have it ring on my android device running sipdroid.  Just once.   Since then, when I call my ipkall number, I get "The person at extension .... is unavailable".

I can see my incoming call history on the sip2sip website, in my accts call history.  That one good call is green.  The rest are in red.

I can't find any documentation for what the red even means.

Why would it work once, and then stop?  How can I fix it?